# How To Select And Join two table with last record in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i want join last row is_read column in ticket_message table to tickets table.
i used this sample code and the results are not sorted by id.

```
SELECT t.*,m.is_read
FROM tickets AS t
LEFT JOIN ticket_message AS m ON t.id = m.ticket_id 
LEFT JOIN ticket_message AS m1 ON m.ticket_id = m1.ticket_id 
               AND m.id < m1.id
WHERE m1.id IS NULL
```

```
$this->db->select('t.*,m.is_read');
$this->db->from('tickets as t');
$this->db->join('ticket_message as m', 't.id = m.ticket_id', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('ticket_message as m1', 'm.ticket_id = m1.ticket_id AND m.id < m1.id', 'left'); 
$this->db->where('m1.id IS NULL', null, false);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```

[image: tickets table]
[image: ticket_message table]
[image: sql query result]
what do i do.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a text with a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted by ID? I assume you mean ordered by ID.. in which case you just add this to your build query:

```
$this->db->order_by('t.id', 'ASC');
```

Your whole query:

```
$this->db->select('t.*,m.is_read');
$this->db->from('tickets as t');
$this->db->join('ticket_message as m', 't.id = m.ticket_id', 'left'); 
$this->db->join('ticket_message as m1', 'm.ticket_id = m1.ticket_id AND m.id < m1.id', 'left'); 
$this->db->where('m1.id IS NULL', null, false);
$this->db->order_by('t.id', 'ASC');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query;
```